# Unauthorised error 401 returns internal server error 500

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have deployed my spring boot web application on local machine embedded apache server using spring ide and accessing an url with incorrect token, in this case it returns me unauthorised access error 401 and a specific error message which throwed by managed exception handling whereas if i deploy same application on independent but same apache server, it gives me 500 internal server error in place of 401 or any other server side error.

The log i have captured have only following one line difference:

```
local
------------------
2021-10-13 16:59:51 - Authentication Failed. Invalid signature in token.
2021-10-13 16:59:51 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/myapplication] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Authentication Failed. Invalid signature in token.

server
------------------
2021-10-13 16:59:35 - Authentication Failed. Invalid signature in token.
2021-10-13 16:59:35 - Forwarding to error page from request [/user/get_user_profile] due to exception [Authentication Failed. Invalid signature in token.]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Authentication Failed. Invalid signature in token.
```

Following is the config i am using to handle exception:

```
@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("admin/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

This is the class which is handling exception:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -90731367144543199L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response,
                     AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        response.getOutputStream().println(authException);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of throwing exceptions in the filter, you should set its status like this :

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);  
response.getWriter().write("Here will be your message string"); //show error message
return;
```